# uploading aab file to Crashlytic Fabric io

Tags: google-fabric, crashlytics-android, android-app-bundle

Anyone have any idea when Crashlytic or Fabric io will ever support the new android app bundle format aab file? I'm currently updating all my jenkins deployment pipeline to generate aab file rather than apk file.

cheers

Answer (score 15):

Mike from Fabric here. It is not on our roadmap to support aab's within Beta by Crashlytics. It's something being discussed for Firebase App Distribution (the successor to Beta).

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's a shame though!

Comment: @MikeBonnell If we deploy an AAB to the Google Play Store and upload an APK to Crashlytics for the same release, can we expect to still receive crash logs? Or am I being too optimistic?

Comment: Crash collection shouldn't be affected if you're using an aab or apk.

Comment: @MikeBonnell thanks! should they also behave the same? i.e., if my beta users tested the version using the Crahslytics/APK, and everything worked well – should I expect it work well also with AAB from Google Play?

Comment: I believe so, but I no longer work on the product so my information may be out of date.